# How to round a calculated field in mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
select *, sum(price+shipping+paypalfee+storefee) as totalcost, customerpaid as totalrevenue, 
(customerpaid - sum(price+shipping+paypalfee+storefee)) as profit,
(((customerpaid - sum(price+shipping+paypalfee+storefee)) / customerpaid) * 100.00) as profitpercent
from tblsales 
group by orderno having " . $having . " 
order by $sort $order limit $offset,$rows"
```

The query works fine **how could I round profitpercent**, a calculated field.

Comment: Why are you using `select *` with a `group by`?

Comment: I'm gonna change that :)

Answer (score 1):

Use ROUND function as mentioned [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) So your query would be:

```
SELECT orderno, sum(price+shipping+paypalfee+storefee) as totalcost, customerpaid AS totalrevenue, (customerpaid - sum(price+shipping+paypalfee+storefee)) AS profit, ROUND((((customerpaid - sum(price+shipping+paypalfee+storefee)) / customerpaid) * 100.00)) AS profitpercent
FROM tblsales 
GROUP BY orderno HAVING " . $having . " 
ORDER BY $sort $order LIMIT $offset,$rows"
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally

```
ROUND( expression, 2 )
```

so try this

```
select *, sum(price+shipping+paypalfee+storefee) as totalcost, customerpaid as totalrevenue, 
(customerpaid - sum(price+shipping+paypalfee+storefee)) as profit,
ROUND((((customerpaid - sum(price+shipping+paypalfee+storefee)) / customerpaid) * 100.00),2) as profitpercent
from tblsales 
group by orderno having " . $having . " 
order by $sort $order limit $offset,$rows"
```